# Tools for automatic deployment of JavaScript, CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, deployment, project-management, minify

I am looking for a solution to automate my project workflow a bit.

Let's say I have the following folder structure:

project
---- less
-------- project.less
---- css
-------- project.min.css
---- js
-------- project.js
-------- project.min.js
---- index.html

Are there any tools (Mac) out there so I can manage this project so that:

- project.js is used while building the project but only project.min.js gets deployed
- again, project.less is used while building the project but only project.min.css gets deployed

Or do I manually need to change paths and minify files?

Comment: using node.js, ruby, python you could write some pretty simple compression/deployment scripts.  Personally I would use node.js and simply install `uglify-js` and do some fs read and writes, but any scripting language or even bash would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably write something using Capistrano, which while Rails focussed can be used to deploy anything. I have used it for PHP projects, for example.

Another option would be to base your project off the HTML5 boiler plate (which uses ant) as this will build/concatenate stuff for you and could be extended to deploy just what you need.

I think I would use some local scripts and Capistrano.